# SQL query, specify which top results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query that current returns the top 50 rows from a query.

```
LEFT JOIN users u
ON c.id = u.id
ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 50;
```

I would like to change the LIMIT 50 to be dynamic, so I could specify results 1-24, 25-50, etc.  How can I change LIMIT 50 to work this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 0, 25;

ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 25, 25;

ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 75, 25;


$page = 0; // 1, 2, 3
$perPage = 25;

$query = ' ... ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT ' . ( $page * $perPage ) . ', ' . $perPage;
```

Answer (score 2):

like this

`LIMIT 0,25`

`LIMIT 25,25`

or

`LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0`

`LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25`

Syntax is:

`[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]`

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only retrieve a consecutive range of rows using `LIMIT`.

However, you can merge two results together in a `UNION`:

```
(
    SELECT
    ...
    LEFT JOIN users u
    ON c.id = u.id
    ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 1,25;
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
    ...
    LEFT JOIN users u
    ON c.id = u.id
    ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 25,26;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont like that comma, you can use the syntax

```
LIMIT 0 OFFSET 25
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
```